# Handling summations with two variables

Tags: probability, combinatorics, summation, factorial

If I have a summation with let's say $x=0 \dots 500$ and $y=0\dots1500$

$500 \choose x$ $ 1500 \choose y$ $\dfrac{1}{2^{500}}\dfrac{2^{1500-y}}{3^{1500}}$,

How would I handle the constant? If I split the summations apart into two separate one's would I include it in both? And when splitting them, would I add or multiply the two summations?

Comment: Do you mean $$\sum_{x=0}^{500}\sum_{y=0}^{1500}\binom{500}x\binom{1500}y\frac1{2^{500}}\cfrac{2^{1500-y}}{3^{1500}}$$ or something else? (That last bit is supposed to be a fraction. Not sure why it isn't displaying right.)

Comment: @CameronBuie:  somehow your cfrac doesn't like display mode.  dfrac has the same problem.  It works with the plain frac $$\sum_{x=0}^{500}\sum_{y=0}^{1500}\binom{500}x\binom{1500}y\frac1{2^{500}}\frac {2^{1500-y}}{3^{1500}}$$

Comment: @Ross: Regular frac wasn't working for me, either. It just wrote $$2^{1500-y}3^{1500},$$ for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you mean $$\sum_{x=0}^{500}\sum_{y=0}^{1500}\binom{500}x\binom{1500}y\frac1{2^{500}}\frac{2^{1500-y}}{3^{1500}},$$ there are a few useful things to observe. Since the sum is finite, we can switch the order to $$\sum_{y=0}^{1500}\sum_{x=0}^{500}\binom{500}x\binom{1500}y\frac1{2^{500}}\frac{2^{1500-y}}{3^{1500}}.$$ Now, we can pull constant multiples out to the front (because of distributivity), giving us $$\frac1{2^{500}3^{1500}}\sum_{y=0}^{1500}\sum_{x=0}^{500}\binom{500}x\binom{1500}y2^{1500-y}.$$ Now, again by distributivity, we can factor out the sum of the $x$ terms, giving us $$\frac1{2^{500}3^{1500}}\left[\sum_{x=0}^{500}\binom{500}x\right]\left[\sum_{y=0}^{1500}\binom{1500}y2^{1500-y}\right].$$

The sum of the $x$ terms is $2^{500},$ giving us $$\frac1{3^{1500}}\sum_{y=0}^{1500}\binom{1500}y2^{1500-y}$$ after cancellation. Now we're down to one sum, and I leave the rest to you.

---

**Edit**: You've discovered the trick of using binomial expansion to get the last sum done (excellent work). I'll add that here in the answer, so that future users might see how it was done. Hover over the white space below to see it.

> Since $(a+b)^{1500}=\sum\limits_{y=0}^{1500}\binom{1500}ya^yb^{1500-y},$ then using $a=1$ and $b=2$ shows us that the final sum is $1$.

Comment: When would switching the order in your second step have an effect?

Comment: Also in terms of the constant multiple, why don't we multiply it by 500 or 1500?

Comment: Largely, I just did that to make clear that the sum of all the $x$ terms was being multiplied by every $y$ term, so that we could factor it out at the end. There wasn't really a *need* to do it, but I wanted to make sure you realized that doing so didn't change the sum.

Comment: Distributivity says that $a*b+a*c=a*(b+c)$, not (as your logic would suggest) $a*b+a*c=2a*(b+c)$. We simply factor out the constant multiple, and don't adjust it further. Now, if we had a constant *summand*, like a $+z$ term in there at every stage, then we would break up the sum as the sum we had, plus $$\sum_{y=0}^{1500}\sum_{x=0}^{500}z=\sum_{y=0}^{1500}501*z=1501*501*z.$$

Comment: Why does it not change the sum though? If we have the summation from n = 1 to 10 of the number 5, it comes to 5*10, right? Is that not a constant?

Comment: Sorry about all the questions, but also what does the order of the sigma mean exactly? Is it like a double loop? If x goes to 500 and y goes to 1500, what happens when x gets to 500 and y continues?

Comment: Ah! I see where your confusion is coming from. We actually do the same thing in the case of just adding up the constant: $$\sum_{n=1}^{10}5=5*\sum_{n=1}^{10}1=5*10.$$ The $*10$ comes about when we actually evaluate the sum of $1$s. We don't need to put it in beforehand, too.

Comment: You can certainly think about it as a double loop. $$\sum_{x=0}^{500}\sum_{y=0}^{1500}f(x,y)$$ means that we start with $x=0$ and add up $$f(0,0)+f(0,1)+\cdots+f(0,1500),$$ then tick $x$ up by $1$ and add up $$f(1,0)+f(1,1)+\cdots+f(1,1500),$$ continuing this trend until we finally add up $$f(500,0)+f(500,1)+\cdots+f(500,1500).$$ It's the same idea with $$\sum_{y=0}^{1500}\sum_{x=0}^{500}f(x,y),$$ starting with $$f(0,0)+f(1,0)+\cdots+f(500,0),$$ and ticking up $y$ until we finally get to $$f(0,1500)+f(1,1500)+\cdots+f(500,1500).$$

It turns out that this makes no difference. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) We add up all the same terms in either case because addition is commutative and associative. And if we have the case (as we did here) that $f(x,y)=g(x)*h(y)$, then we can split the nested loops into a product of separate loops because of distributivity.

Comment: I got 1 as an answer. Given that the binomial theorem is (x+y)^n. Is 1 correct?

Comment: Nicely done! ${}$